# sqlite3 UPDATE generating nulls

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to transition from MySQL to SQLIte3 and running into an update problem. I'm using SQLite 3.6.20 on redhat.

My first line of code behaves normally

```
 update atv_covar set noncomp= 2;
```

All values for noncomp (in the rightmost column) are appropriately set to 2.

```
select * from atv_covar;
A5202|S182|2
A5202|S183|2
A5202|S184|2
```

It is the second line of code that gives me problems:

```
 update atv_covar 
 set noncomp= (select 1 from f4003 where
               atv_covar.study = f4003.study and 
               atv_covar.rpid = f4003.rpid and 
               (rsoffrx="81" or rsoffrx="77"));
```

It runs without generating errors and appropriately sets atv_covar.noncomp to 1 where it matches the SELECT statement. The problem is that it changes atv_covar.noncomp for the non-matching rows to null, where I want it to keep them as 2.

```
select * from atv_covar;
A5202|S182|
A5202|S183|1
A5202|S184|
```

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

@Dan, the problem with your query is not specific to SQLite; you are updating all rows of `atv_covar`, but not all of them have correspondence in `f4003`, so these default to NULL. You should filter the update or provide a default value.

The following statement sets 1 only to the rows that macth the filtering condition:

```
 UPDATE atv_covar
 SET noncomp = 1
 WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT 'x'
     FROM f4003
     WHERE atv_covar.study = f4003.study
       AND atv_covar.rpid = f4003.rpid
       AND (rsoffrx="81" or rsoffrx="77")
 );
```

The following statement sets 1 or 2 for all rows of noncomp, depending on the filtering match (use this instead of two updates):

```
 UPDATE atv_covar
 SET noncomp = COALESCE((
     SELECT 1
     FROM f4003
     WHERE atv_covar.study = f4003.study
       AND atv_covar.rpid = f4003.rpid
       AND (rsoffrx="81" or rsoffrx="77")
 ), 2);
```